# How to remove delimiter from response in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I created proxy service on wso2 developer studio. All things work correctly. But when I send request through TCP Client I added delimiter to the request. When I run the project response comes to the tcp client withing delimiter.

Here is my TCPClient.java file

```html
package esb.cellcard.billing;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient {
 public static void main(String argv[]){
   try {
    
    int modifiedSentence;
   
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6050);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String addSubscriptionMessage = "XAWS#234516#768$890?"; //delimiter is ?
    
   
    outToServer.writeBytes(addSubscriptionMessage);
    outToServer.flush();
    while ((modifiedSentence = inFromServer.read()) > -1){
        System.out.print((char)modifiedSentence);
    }
      clientSocket.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Proxy service

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TestProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="tcp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <class description="" name="esb.test.MediatorTest"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="TestEP"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <class name="esb.test.Response"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <ms11:text xmlns:ms11="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ms11:text>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('responseClientValue')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/plain"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.responseClient">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.inputType">string</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiter">?</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.port">9080</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiterType">character</parameter>
</proxy>
```

> delimiter value is "**?**" (Question mark)

Response Is

> XAWS234516768890xaw?

But I need to remove this ? character from response. I tried many ways.[This](http://harshcreationz.blogspot.com/2015/02/two-way-tcp-transport-wso2-esb.html) post helped to me get some idea.But I couldn't get the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you receive response in tcp client in same socket connection. You defined separator char '?'  and you will get it in console when you run TCPClient. But inside of synapse message doesn't contain any question mark at the end.

This is easy to check. Add log mediator, right at the begging

```
<log>
  <property name="----------------" expression="$body/*" />
</log>
```

In esb log you will notice

```
[2017-07-18 13:18:14,324] []  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, 
SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:891D4827AC4E28A2AA1500373094318, 
Direction: request, -------------------- = MSGID=WZ2OCS2:1:14:14008:1:@1479122000#AddBun;
Account ID= 919408089154;Bundle ID =MHVOICE122;
Bundle Name=1,LAnyNet1.4p/2Sec;Bundle Expiry Date=26-01-2017;
Bundle Start Date=26-01-2016;Recharge Amount=0.00;SUCCESS1479122001
```

There is not any question mark.

Another case to prove is to change messageType. I just slightly changed your proxy

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="SurepayBillingErrorHandlingProxy"
   startOnLoad="true"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="disable"
   transports="tcp">
<target>
  <inSequence>
     <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/xml"/>
     <property name="contentType" scope="axis2" value="application/xml"/>
     <log>
        <property expression="$body/*" name="--------------------"/>
     </log>
     <send>
        <endpoint key="httplab"/>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
     <respond/>
  </outSequence>
  <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.responseClient">true</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.inputType">string</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiter">?</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">text/plain</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6050</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.recordDelimiterType">character</parameter>
<description/>
</proxy>
```

in this proxy endpoint key="httplab" is just http server which just logs incoming message.

Result is on picture underneath.

[image]

Comment: Thank you simar.Your correct. I also added log mediator for check body. That is fine.Its doesn't appear any question mark. Problem is when come response to the client there is question mark.And I need to send json payload to service there for I use application/json after class mediator.

Comment: Simar are you saying we can't remove this delimiter from response

Comment: From response to TCPClient - you can't. Over-wise how tcpclient can separate received messages. But delimiter is not the part of payload.

Comment: Thank you.Is this wso2 bug.

Comment: That is not a bug. That is a protocol. There are 2 way to detect message in tcp stream. Either to send delimiter either to send size of message in front of message, so other side will be able to detect end of message and start to process it.